# Why is super(id) not being accepted?

Tags: java, html, wicket

I'm coding a website with a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu has a HTML panel and a Java.

The Java of the dropdown menu panel

```
 package website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.houses;

 import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage; import
 org.apache.wicket.settings.MarkupSettings; import
 org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.BookmarkablePageLink; import
 org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link; import
 org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RepeatingView; import
 org.apache.wicket.model.Model; import
 org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters; import
 org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;

 import website.fgto.royals_of_britain.service.HousesService;

 public class HousesDropdown extends WebPage {
      public HousesDropdown(String id) {
     super(id);

     add(buildDropdownLinks());   }
```

The Java of the Homepage

```
     package website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.houses;

     import org.apache.wicket.markup.head.CssHeaderItem; import org.apache.wicket.markup.head.IHeaderResponse; import
 org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage; import
 org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label; import
 org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters; import
 org.apache.wicket.request.resource.CssResourceReference; import
 website.fgto.royals_of_britain.WicketApplication; import
 website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.Apology; import
 website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.Footer; import
 website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.houses.intros.*; import
 website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.kings.KingsTableRows;

     public class HouseInformationPage extends WebPage {   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public HouseInformationPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
         super(parameters);

         String houseName = parameters.get("houseName").toString();

         add(new Label("houseName", houseName));
         add(new HousesDropdown("housesDropdown"));
         add(new Footer("footerPanel"));
```

So the problem is that if I keep it like so, IntelliJ says there is a lack of Java method for the *id* to be a string. But if I take out the *super(id)* then it says there is a difference in length between the actual and the formal arguments.

Comment: what constructor is there in the WebPage class?

Answer (score 2):

WebPage provides 3 constructors:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html

A default one, one that takes an instance of IModel and one that accepts PageParameters as parameter.

A String isn't a valid parameter for this constructor call.

Since your class extends `WebPage`, if in your constructor you call `super();` or `super(x);`, you are, in fact, trying to call one of WebPages constructors, and have to provide correct parameters.

Comment: 1. String id: OK so my website is about the dynasties that have reigned on the island of Britain. The string id pulls up a dynastic name that is one of the hyperlinks in the dropdown menu, each time for all the menu’s links. 

2. A prior problem: My wickets were pulling up li elements from the child container with multiple a elements instead of each li element with its own a element. My “solution” was to move the wicket on the home page to ul element of the dropdown. That’s when IntelliJ objects to the string id.

Comment: the moment when is not relevant. WebPage does not have a constructor accepting a single String as parameter. That's why it fails. This is not IntelliJ related. Your super(id); is trying to call a non-existing constructor in the parent class (WebPage)

Comment: Clearly the problem is that I'm using WebPage. How do I get WebPage (PageParameters parameters) instead?

Comment: The problem isn't that you are using WebPage. How do you get PageParameters for your HouseInformation class?

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, my mistake was to replace Panel with WebPage in the constructor. So my line of questioning is moot. But there are questions that I still have, now that I'm sticking with the Panel for the construction of my Dropdown menu. If you're interested, post a comment on the thread for my *next* question!